# Eclipse RCP: How to display source code?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I was wandering if it's possible to open a source code in text editor and display it with decorations (Java for example)? I don't need fancy eclipse editor features, just properly decorated source code with line numbers, it can even be read-only. I read that RCP have many limitations with text editors as it drags behind heavy plug-ins. Can it be done at all? Is it possible to navigate to particular line of code when file is opened? It would be really great if someone would point me out to the right direction or give some examples... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I have found a solution. I didn't go with eclipse text plugins - it was extreamly complex and heavy weight for what I really needed. There is much simpler solution based on StyledText SWT widget. It is very light and quite powerful for doing text decorations. I've even found ready to use source code from eclipse swt examples which shows Java source properly formatted. Google for JavaViewer, with  simple twick it can be transformed into any source code viewer... Asusual, eclipse has wealth of information - all you need to do is to find it !

Comment: That would be really great if you share link to the example.

Comment: Here you go - these things I borrowed from the examples, we have it successfully integrated into our product : http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/downloads/source-viewer.zip, run the JavaViewer and choose the source file to display. And this is an example how it sits in our application: http://www.moonlit-software.com/logfaces/web/images/screens/full/sources.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse (3.4.2) itself ships with a sample XML editor that implements syntax highlighting. Just create a new plugin project, select 'This plugin will make contributions to the UI' and choose 'No' for Rich client application. The following wizard page offers a 'Plugin with an editor' template, which is your friend.

It may be too simple to use it as real template for your task, but it demonstrate how to create colourful editors for text files.

Comment: WOW thanks, this saved me from using that wst.ui.structuredtexteditor which comes with a lot of dependencies! :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm implementing a eclipse plugin which focusing on TTCN language, the editor is the most important part for it. actually, i'm using Eclipse editor framework. i guess there are quite more useful features than you want. And it's easy to extended.As Andreads_D said, you can find reference to the basic example which eclipse provided defaultly. I guess you don't need to know everything about it, just fousing on your needs. Also you can reference https://quitus-kitt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk. Any problem, we can discuss. : )

Comment: Eclipse editor framework is so massive and drags behind it so many plugins that the whole idea of using it put me off in the first place. As I mentioned, the easiest way to display decorated source code is to use plain StyledText widget.